# Как взять N символов строки экономично для памяти?

Tags: java, строки, утечка-памяти

У меня есть база ИНН. Нужно взять первые два символа. База большая, требования в памяти жесткие.
Какие из этих способов извлечения символов экономичны?

1. Можно разбить строку на массив `split("")` и взять первые два значения
2. `new String(string, 0, 1);`
3. `int start = 0; int end = 2; char buf[] = new char[end - start];`
4. `substring(0,2)`

Comment: Вы же можете померять каждый вариант.

Comment: Значит надо работать с потоками Stream и не запихивать всю базу в память. Из вопроса непонятно что Вы хотите сделать с первыми двумя символами после извлечения. Итого: лучше в потоке частями читать эту "базу", и сразу же как-то обрабатывать, освобождая память.

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы достаете из базы данные. Самый оптимальный вариант на мой взгляд - доставать уже из базы только первые два символа, хранить в байтовом массиве длины 2 * recordsCount (ИНН это же ведь только цифры, умещающиеся в 1 байт)

Comment: Изначально выбирайте из БД только два символа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны понимать, что стринг изначально неизменяемый. К каким бы вы хитростям не прибегали, вы будете плодить объекты. Сплит исключите сразу. Массив чаров... С ним работать не удобно, тогда уже лучше charAt(0) и charAt(1). получит по цифире в каждом чаре, а чар по факту не занимает много места. сабстринг и нбю стринг создаст новый объект типа стринг со всемы вытекающими. посему при больших объемах и ограниченных ресурсах рекомендации заставить это делать бд - правильное решение. вплоть до создания отдельной колонки с 2 цифрами, это даст возможность простого поиска нужных комбинаций. ну если с бд для вас совсем не вариант, а ресурсы грузить все не позволяют, есть еще такая полезная штука, как пагинация - загрузка данных из бд по частям.